# In Mysql / Sql . How can a make a column take as default the values of an other one

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a column order_id that takes as default the values of id_task.[image]

For exemple if I enter a new row without specifying the "order_id" value, it should take the same value that "id_task" will take (auto-incremented).

Thanks

Comment: I think you would need to use a trigger for this.  I don't think you can set a default value to an auto increment column.

Comment: If it was nullable, then you could just use COALESCE in your select to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @vahdet I think that a have the same problem as this post